# Open command prompt using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to Java and am trying to run a program using Eclipse. But I have no idea how to get the command prompt running in with Eclipse...

I did some online research and couldn't get anything consolidated!

#### Update:

I'm not using an applet. It's a normal Java program trying to read a line from command prompt. I'm trying to do system programming.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out this lesson plan on how to get started with Eclipse programs:

[Lesson](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~thornton/ics22/LabManual/Lab0/)

Specifically, see this image:

[image: Picture of Eclipse Console with Standard Input]

If the Console tab is not visible in your Eclipse, go to Window -> Show View -> Console in the menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded the Eclipse/Java package, and you wrote a Java program in Eclipse in a project, just click compile and run, it will run in the output window in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:


import java.util.Scanner;

    public class ReadFromPrompt{

       public static void main(String[] args) {

           Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

           String line = in.nextLine();     

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Right Click on your project--->Run As--->Run Configurations...--->Select Arguments-->Enter the values---->Run
```